# Using several conditions for ng-disabled

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

I'd like to disable my submit button in a form if the user hasn't typed a minimum of 50 characters in the field. I've thought of using a condition like this:

```
ng-disabled="addJobForm.$invalid && myInput.length > 50"
```

However it is not working. What I don't understand is that if I print the value of my condition like this:

```
{{addJobForm.$invalid && myInput.length > 50}}
```

The values are correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it seems fine... ng-disable expect an expression so you should not use {{addJobForm.$invalid && myInput.length > 50}}... here is working plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:FrTqqTNoY8BEfHs9bB0f

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use **ng-minlength=50** in your input element and remove the second condition from submit button.So till your input field is not valid submit button remains in disable state.There are also other attributes also like ng-maxlength or ng-pattern(For regular expression).

For more details you can read this documentation [Angular's input validation](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/validations.html).

Comment: adding ng-minlength works to disable the submit button. However, I have a character counter (i.e. <small>enter at least {{50 - myInput.length}} characters</small>) which stopped working when I added ng-minlength. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Try to move this code into scope. Something like

```
$scope.invalidFormOrLimitExceeded = function() { 
   return 'addJobForm.$invalid && myInput.length > 50'
}

ng-disabled="invalidFormOrLimitExceeded()"
```

And look if it helps

Answer (score 0):

try replacing "&&" by `&amp; &amp;`